# In Synfony 2 after adding @UniqueEntity("description") it takes duplicate value for description

Tags: symfony

```
//Events.php
<?php

namespace erp\GenerateBundle\Entity;


use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * Events
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="description", message="Already Exists")
 */
class Events
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(type = "string", unique = true)
     * @Assert/Description()
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $eventdate;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $duration;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $createdby;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $added;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updated;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \erp\GenerateBundle\Entity\User
     */
    private $userid;

    /**
     * @var \erp\GenerateBundle\Entity\EventType
     */
    private $eventtype;


    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Events
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set eventdate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $eventdate
     * @return Events
     */
    public function setEventdate($eventdate)
    {
        $this->eventdate = $eventdate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get eventdate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getEventdate()
    {
        return $this->eventdate;
    }

    /**
     * Set duration
     *
     * @param integer $duration
     * @return Events
     */
    public function setDuration($duration)
    {
        $this->duration = $duration;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get duration
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getDuration()
    {
        return $this->duration;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdby
     *
     * @param integer $createdby
     * @return Events
     */
    public function setCreatedby($createdby)
    {
        $this->createdby = $createdby;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdby
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getCreatedby()
    {
        return $this->createdby;
    }

    /**
     * Set added
     *
     * @param \DateTime $added
     * @return Events
     */
    public function setAdded($added)
    {
        $this->added = $added;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get added
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getAdded()
    {
        return $this->added;
    }

    /**
     * Set updated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updated
     * @return Events
     */
    public function setUpdated($updated)
    {
        $this->updated = $updated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updated
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUpdated()
    {
        return $this->updated;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set userid
     *
     * @param \erp\GenerateBundle\Entity\User $userid
     * @return Events
     */
    public function setUserid(\erp\GenerateBundle\Entity\User $userid = null)
    {
        $this->userid = $userid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userid
     *
     * @return \erp\GenerateBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getUserid()
    {
        return $this->userid;
    }

    /**
     * Set eventtype
     *
     * @param \erp\GenerateBundle\Entity\EventType $eventtype
     * @return Events
     */
    public function setEventtype(\erp\GenerateBundle\Entity\EventType $eventtype = null)
    {
        $this->eventtype = $eventtype;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get eventtype
     *
     * @return \erp\GenerateBundle\Entity\EventType 
     */
    public function getEventtype()
    {
        return $this->eventtype;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Config.yml

framework:
validation:      { enabled: true, enable_annotations: true}

In Controller 
check isValid() 
If it is not there then add. isValid() before submission of form .

Answer (score 0):

I can hardly decipher your problem. Are there any error messages? Where is the problem in persisting to the db or submitting a form?

But I see some problems in the code you post it.

1. Annotation `@Assert/Description()` doesn't exist.
2. In the example you're missing `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;`
3. You should use `@ORM\Column(type = "string", unique = true)` if you use ORM alias instead of `@Column`